# Evenly distribute textviews across linear layout horizontally and wrap content

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to programmatically add some textviews inside a linear layout. I want these textviews to evenly distribute across the width of the linear layout and i want the textviews to wrap their content.

I create the textviews like that, but they dont wrap their content.

```
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(mContext);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    params.setMargins(40, 0, 0, 0);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
   // linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);

    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    for(String label: labels) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(mContext);
        textView.setText(label.trim());
        textView.setTextSize(13);
        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        textView.setTextColor(R.color.labels_color);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams mlp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
        mlp.setMargins(0,0,20,0);

        textView.setLayoutParams(mlp);
        linearLayout.addView(textView);
    }
    chartWrapper.addView(linearLayout);
```

Comment: did you manage to pull it of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by assigning weight to 1 to all TextViews except the last one.

```
    public void drawLabels(List<String> labelsValues, ViewGroup container) {


    for (int i = 0; i < labelsValues.size(); i++) {
        String label = labelsValues.get(i);
        TextView textView = new TextView(mContext);
        textView.setText(label.trim());

        if (i == labelsValues.size() - 1) {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            textView.setLayoutParams(params);
        } else {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
            textView.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
        container.addView(textView);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use weightsum and weight with LinearLayout for distributing items evenly and you are using only weight as far as i can see. Without a proper weightsum, the linearlayout will not know how to distribute.

If that doesnt work, try setting the width to 0, I think its a rquirement for weight to work properly. But you want your textviews to have wrap_content so maybe you should put the textview in a layout and give the layout 0 width so you can make your textview wrap_content.

Comment: He is already using weights (`new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);`) - that 1f is weight value

Comment: @krossovochkin thanks for pointing that out! I edited the post. I actually meant weightsum instead of gravity.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams mlp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
```

Use zero as width:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams mlp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

> I want these textviews to evenly distribute across the width of the linear layout and i want the textviews to wrap their content

You're aiming for two contradicting designs, either the width of the TextView is according to its content (WRAP_CONTENT) or it's the width of the LinearLayout divided by the number of TextViews inside it.

If you want a TextView to wrap its content then define it in the LayoutParams just as you did.
If you want to divide the width of the LinearLayout evenly then set the gravity of the TextView to 1 and its width to 0.

BTW, `textView.setTextSize(13);` sets the size in pixels and is not recommended, you should use dp or sp instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea that you add margin for each items. It works with small number of items, but if you are adding like 10 items, those margins will push contents too much.

I created a project that handles textview dynamically (landscape and portrait) with using LinearLayout and ConstraintLayout 
https://github.com/SwordArtist/DynamicEvenSpreadingView

Hope it helps